# Python: get a complete file name based on a partial file name

Tags: python

In a directory, there are two files that share most of their names:

```
my_file_0_1.txt
my_file_word_0_1.txt
```

I would like to open `my_file_0_1.txt`

I need to avoid specifying the exact filename, and instead need to search the directory for a filename that matches the partial string `my_file_0`.

From [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25984107/find-a-file-in-a-directory-using-python-by-partial-name), [and this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724693/find-a-file-in-python), I tried the following:

```
import numpy as np
import os, fnmatch, glob

def find(pattern, path):
        result = []
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
                for name in files:
                        if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pattern):
                                result.append(os.path.join(root, name))
        return result

if __name__=='__main__':

        #filename=find('my_file_0*.txt', '/path/to/file')
        #print filename
        print glob.glob('my_file_0' + '*' + '.txt')
```

Neither of these would print the actual filename, for me to read in later using `np.loadtxt`.

How can I find and store the name of a file, based on the result of a string match?

Comment: `glob.glob` is the way to go, I think. `glob.glob('my_file_0*.txt')` returns a list of file names, use indexing to retrieve the file you need.

Comment: Agreed. `glob.glob` is a wrapper around `fnmatch`, but it's a wrapper that does exactly what you want to do right here.

Comment: @StatsSorceress make sure you have this files in the directory you run you script as `glob` should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`glob.glob()` needs a path to be efficient, if you are running the script in another directory, it will not find what you expect.
(you can check the current directory with `os.getcwd()`)

It should work with the line below  :

```
print glob.glob('path/to/search/my_file_0' + '*.txt')
```

or

```
print glob.glob(r'C:\path\to\search\my_file_0' + '*.txt') # for windows
```

Answer (score 1):

## A solution using [os.listdir()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_listdir.htm)

Could you not also use the `os` module to search through `os.listdir()`? So for instance:

```
import os

partialFileName = "my_file_0"

for f in os.listdir():
    if partialFileName = f[:len(partialFileName)]:
        print(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just developed the approach below and was doing a search to see if there was a better way and came across your question. I think you may like this approach. I needed pretty much the same thing you are asking for and came up with this clean one liner using list comprehension and a sure expectation that there would only be one file name matching my criteria. I modified my code to match your question.

```
import os


file_name = [n for n in os.listdir("C:/Your/Path") if 'my_file_0' in n][0]
print(file)
```

Now, if this is in a looping / repeated call situation, you can modify as below:

```
for i in range(1, 4):
    file = [n for n in os.listdir("C:/Your/Path") if f'my_file_{i}' in n][0]
    print(file)
```

or, probably more practically ...

```
def get_file_name_with_number(num):
    file = [n for n in os.listdir("C:/Your/Path") if f'my_file_{num}' in n][0]
    return file


print(get_file_name_with_number(0))
```